# Trouble implementing a "rope" data structure in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, ropes

I'm trying to make a [rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29) data structure. It's a type of binary tree, i.e. a recursive data structure.

The purpose of a rope is that splitting and concatenation should be *fast*, which means *you avoid copying entire ropes*.
So, for example, a user should be able to say `rope1 + rope2` and expect a result in ~logarithmic time.

However, this presents a problem:
If a rope is modified, its parents are indirectly modified as well.
Because my goal is to make `rope` a drop-in replacement for `string`, this is not acceptable.

My solution to this is: Whenever there is *any* kind of change to a `rope`, I would create a *new* node, with a slight change, leaving the old ones unmodified.

In theory, I think this would work rather well.

In practice, though, it involves a heap allocation *for (almost?) every modification* of the strings.
Even a one-character change would result in a new heap object, which is not only slow by itself, but which also significantly decreases memory locality, very negatively impacting performance.

How should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: So, you want splitting and concatenation to be fast, but also everything else to be fast? I think this is a case of "you cannot eat your cake and have it too."

Comment: If you have GCC, check the `<ext/rope>` header for an example implementation.

Comment: "Because my goal is to make rope a drop-in replacement for string," You *cannot* make a `rope` a drop-in replacement for `string`. By definition, they are two different data structures with two different sets of operations. `string`, in C++11, is required to be *contiguous*, which your rope is not.

Comment: You only need to make the heap allocation/copy if it's also referenced by another string.  You'd quickly end up in a situation where all those copies happened eventually, just later and using more overhead.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Yeah I was afraid of that...

Comment: @NicolBolas: Well, short of taking the address I mean. :) I didn't mean it would be 100% compliant though, just usable in general.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Hmm... so are you suggesting I reference count it?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Were you really planning on doing copy-on-write _without_ reference counting or a GC?  I'm not even sure if it's possible.  Anyway, what I intended to suggest is to have `rope1 + rope2` do a deep copy.  But now that I think some more on it, reference counting/COW might be competitive in terms of speed.  I'm not sure.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Well I was juggling a few things on my mind, and not doing reference counting was one of them -- I wasn't sure so that's why I asked. My guess is that the speed would be pretty competitive, judging the nature of rope -- it might be a bit slower than string but not by much, so I think I'd probably go that route. (Another alternative in my mind was that the *user* of the class might use a ref count instead of the class itself, but that didn't seem to work out correctly.)

Answer (score 5):

The traditional approach would be copy-on-write: for this, you need to refcount each allocated node.

If the modified node has a refcount of 1 (no-one else refers to it), you don't need to duplicate it.

The practical problem with this is *usefully segregating* mutating from non-mutating operations:

```
    char& rope::operator[] (std::string::pos)
```

*may* mutate the referenced char, but there's no trivial way to force selection of the const overload when it *actually won't*. This means you either have to assume mutation will happen, and possibly trigger an unnecessary copy, or return instead some proxy which overloads char conversion and assignment.

This approach was tried for early implementations of `std::string` (where a string is equivalent to a single-node rope) iirc, and fell out of favour; partly because of the mutation problem, and partly because COW and the required refcounting become increasingly expensive if you have to worry about multi-threading.

---

As you say, the rope has an additional problem if your node contains two independent types of state: its own string and references to its child nodes (since this causes refcount/child reference mutations to propogate up the tree).

If instead the characters are stored only at the leaf nodes, and you do a *full* copy of the non-leaf nodes (so each rope has its own "directory structure") you still avoid copying the characters, and the refcounted shared state is much simpler.

Does this get the logarithmic-time concatenation you want? Perhaps not:

- you have to copy all the non-leaf nodes (and add a new root), and the number of these is log the number of leaves
- you also have to increment the leaf refcounts though, which is linear

Whether it *looks* closer to linear or logarithmic time depends on the relative cost of incrementing a refcount versus copying the directory tree.

Without this though, you get fast concatenations but arbitrary character accesses may (unpredictably) degenerate to logarithmic time if they have to propagate a COW operation up the tree.

I guess, if it suits your use case, you could implement move concatenations: this would give possibly constant-time addition and you still avoid the extra COW complexity.

Comment: +1 for refcounting, seems reasonable. (Still reading the rest -- looks great so far, thanks for the info.)

Answer (score 3):

> In practice, though, it involves a heap allocation for (almost?) every modification of the strings.

If you want to avoid frequent heap allocation performance issues, then I'd suggest using a memory pool for your class that allocates a chunk of memory, and only needs to request a new allocation from the OS when it's full, which should occur pretty infrequently.  You can then optimize accesses to the memory pool for allocating small-block data-types like `char`, etc.

Andrei Alexandrescu has a great example of a small-block memory allocator in his "Modern C++ Design" book.