# Valgrind -- possibly lost warning

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have the code below:

```
std::string myName = "BLABLABLA";

//check if there are illegal characters
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myName.length(); i++)
{
    const char& c = myName[i];
    if (!(isalnum(c) || (c == '_') || (c == '-')))
    {
        return 0;
    }      

}
```

This is the output of valgrind at line "const char& c = myName[i];"

```
==17249== 51 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 116 of 224
==17249==    at 0x4C2714E: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:261)
==17249==    by 0x602A498: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long,       
std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==17249==    by 0x602A689: std::string::_M_mutate(unsigned long, unsigned long,   
unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==17249==    by 0x602AFB5: std::string::_M_leak_hard() (in 
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==17249==    by 0x602B0A4: std::string::operator[](unsigned long) (in /
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
```

I do not see anything wrong with this...

Comment: The devil is in the details. More specifically, inside GCC's `std::string`. It's not your fault. It's not your fault.

Comment: @KerrekSB gcc's string leaking?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Yeah. It's the refcount business...

Comment: Try adding `#define _GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING 1` at the very top of your source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's the horrible COW implementation!
You can also force use of the const (and therefore non-mutating) overloads like so:

```
std::string const myName = "BLABLABLA";

//check if there are illegal characters
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myName.length(); i++)
{
    const char& c = myName[i];
    if (!(isalnum(c) || (c == '_') || (c == '-')))
    {
        return 0;
    }      
}
```

or (if you don't want to modify the original string type):

```
std::string myName = "BLABLABLA";
std::string const &cref = myName;
//check if there are illegal characters
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myName.length(); i++)
{
    const char& c = cref[i];
    if (!(isalnum(c) || (c == '_') || (c == '-')))
    {
        return 0;
    }      
}
```

etc.

---

[COW reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12286841/212858), because I knew I'd written something about it somewhere.